# Expected value with two uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability

A surveyor wishes to lay out a square region with each side having length L. However, because of a measurement error, he instead lays out a rectangle in which the north–south sides both have length X and the east–west sides both have length Y. Suppose that X and Y are independent and that each is uniformly distributed on the interval [L - A, L + A] (where 0 < A < L). What is the expected area of the resulting rectangle?

I tried using $E(x,y) = E(x)E(y) + Cov(x,y) = E(x)E(y)$ (since they are independent)

I ended up with $4A^2L^2$, but the answer should be just $L^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: which is the expected value of a random variable uniformly distributed in the interval $[L-A,L+A]$?

Comment: I believe its (L^2)/2, but then I will end up with (L^4)/4 and not L^2

Comment: Actually, am I supposed to multiply it by 2 instead of multiplying by itself? That will give me the answer, but I don't understand why I would do that

Comment: The expected value of a continuous random variable $x$ is given by $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is the pdf of $x$. Just apply this to get the correct answer.

Comment: Did you get the correct result using the integral of $x f(x)$?

Comment: No. I tried and got 2L/A. I am confused about what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Since the distribution is uniform and the area of the pdf is $1$, we have $f(x)=\frac{1}{2A}$, which can be taken out of the integral as a constant. The remaining part is the integral of $x$ between $L-A$ and $L+A$, which leads to $$1/2[(L+A)^2-(L-A)^2]=2LA$$ Multiplying this result by $\frac{1}{2A}$ you get $L$, which is the expected value of a RV uniformly distributed in that interval.

Comment: Where do you get the 1/2A?

Comment: The area of the probability density function $f(x)$ is by definition $1$. For uniform distributions, the value of $f(x) $ is constant across the range of values of $x$, and then the shape of this function is rectangular. In our case, the range of $x$ (base of the rectangular area identified by this function) is $(L+A)-(L-A)=2A$. Thus, the height of the rectangular area of our pdf, i.e. the constant value of $f(x)$, is $\frac{1}{2A}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If random variable $U$ is uniformly distributed over interval $[-1,1]$ then $U$ and $-U$ have the same distribution, so that  $\mathbb{E}\left(U\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(-U\right)=-\mathbb{E}\left(U\right)$ hence: $$\mathbb{E}\left(U\right)=0$$

Note that $X=L+A.U$ is uniformly distributed over interval $[L-A,L+A]$ and find its expectation making use of the linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find $E( X\cdot Y)$, so we need to integrate $\int_{L-A}^{L+A} \int_{L-A}^{L+A} X \cdot Y \cdot P(X \cap Y) dY dX$
and since X and Y are independent $P(X \cap Y) = P(X) \cdot P(Y)$ and the integrals are separable (note in this case $P(X)=\frac{1}{b-a}=\frac{1}{(L+A)-(L-A)}=\frac{1}{2A}$ which also doesn't depend on X or Y). Once you find they are separable you notice each is the just the definition of expected value ( $E(x)=\int X\cdot P(X) dX$ ).